# I have booked a self service appointment for UK visa and now I see a warning message

Tags: visas, uk

What does this message mean?

[image]

My appointment is tomorrow. I went to the TLS website and they are not showing any changes. What does this mean?.

Comment: How did you receive this message?

Comment: Was this the first and only notification you had?

Comment: yes, it's when i login into my application on the ukvi site

Comment: and it's the only one

Comment: I doubt you have much alternative but to attend your appointment as planned and hope for the best, unless you’ve managed to contact them for clarification meanwhile

Comment: I am attending my appointment as normal and they have no idea about this and mentioning this will do me no good. I will see what happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to the appointment as normal and got my visa two weeks later. Anyone seeing this message should ignore it. I think it was by mistake